# Example of field's normal closure that's not Abelian?

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $K$ is a global field, $L/K$ is a field extension, and $M$ = normal closure of $L$ (over $K$).  Is it possible that Gal($M/L$) is not Abelian?

In all cases I know, $L$ is formed from $K$ by adjoining roots of polynomials of the form $x^n-\alpha$ for some $n\in\Bbb N, \alpha\in K$.  In this case, the normal closure is formed by adjoining all relevant $\zeta_n$, the $n$-th roots of unity.  In this case, the normal closure is always an Abelian extension of $L$.

I think if I used other forms of polynomials, I should get some non-Abelian normal closures; however, I do not have a technique which I can use to identify what Galois groups of such normal closures look like.  Any references would be helpful.

- Relevant question [Intermediate field, normal closure and Galois group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571644/intermediate-field-normal-closure-and-galois-group) did not help.
- Some examples for local fields are provided [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.640.8795&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~desmit/ic/radicalendag/hwl.pdf gives the following example.  $K=\Bbb Q$, $L=K(\alpha)$ where $\alpha^n-\alpha-1=0$.  Then Gal($M/L$) $\cong$ S$_{n-1}$, so is not Abelian.  However, I am not sure why that's true.

Comment: The smallest example that comes to mind is the following. Assume that $M/K$ is the splitting field of an irreducible polynomial $f(x)\in K[x]$ of degree four such that $Gal(M/K)\simeq S_4$. Let $\alpha\in M$ be one of the zeros of $f(x)$ and let $L=K(\alpha)$. Then $M$ is the normal closure of $L/K$ and $Gal(M/L)\simeq S_3$, because that Galois group is the point stabilizer of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x) \in K[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial with Galois group $G$, and let $L = K[x]/f(x)$, so that $M$ is the splitting field of $f$. The Galois group $\text{Gal}(M/L)$ is the stabilizer of any root of $f$ under the action of $G$; we want to find an example where this is nonabelian. To do this we can take $f$ to be an irreducible quartic with Galois group $G = S_4$ (which exist over $\mathbb{Q}$, for example); then the stabilizer of any root is $S_3$, the smallest nonabelian group. This is the smallest possible example.

Comment: Thanks, this explains the example I posted in the comments.